# How to use Omniauth Asana with Rails API only app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, asana

I have a Rails 5 API only app and an Angular JS Frontend app and would like to integrate with Asana API. I'm using the `ruby-asana`, `omniauth` and `omniauth-asana` gems.

I start the request using Asana's [JS library](https://github.com/Asana/node-asana) like so:

```
var client = Asana.Client.create({
      clientId: 172706773623703,
      clientSecret: '<client_secret>',
      redirectUri: '<redirect_url>'
    });
    client.useOauth({
      flowType: Asana.auth.PopFlow
    });
```

And the above does redirect me to Asana where I can login. On the `redirectUri` I'm giving a backend route (Rails 5 API only) which should handle the remaining on the authentication (using the JS only I get only a temporary token that cannot be self renewed meaning the user will have to authenticate every time the token expires. This is if I understood the documentation correctly).

So, on the controller I've created to handle the route, I have the following (from an example on Asana's documentation):

```
require 'omniauth-asana'
use OmniAuth::Strategies::Asana, <secret>, <secret>

creds = request.env["omniauth.auth"]["credentials"].tap { |h| h.delete('expires') }
strategy = request.env["omniauth.strategy"]
access_token = OAuth2::AccessToken.from_hash(strategy.client, creds).refresh!
$client = Asana::Client.new do |c|
  c.authentication :oauth2, access_token
end
```

Now, the above doesn't work because 1) there's no `request.env` as this is an API only app, so I've followed the instruction on [Omniauth](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth#integrating-omniauth-into-your-rails-api) and have added the following to my `config/application.rb`:

```
config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_interslice_session'
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies # Required for all session management
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, config.session_options
```

Now, in the `request.headers` I have `_interslice_session` which has some numbers. How can I create a `Asana client` with the above?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I think I see what you're attempting to do here; I think the best way forward is to start with how OAuth's Authorization Code Grant happens in general, then move into specifics for OmniAuth.

- You send the user to a URL that Asana owns; that is, your goal is to get the user to visit a particular url. For Asana, this is https://app.asana.com/-/oauth_authorize. (Note that we respond with an error if you don't sent a correct `client_id` param, but feel free to check that link if you want). Do **not** send the `client_secret` during this request - it is intended to never be involved in client-side code, as this is insecure.
- If they agree to give access, Asana sends back a redirect request to the user's browser with a short-lived code. That then means that your server will be called from the user's browser with this code as a parameter, so has to handle a **new** incoming request from the browser to whatever you specified as your redirect URI. Also, this location must be accessible by all users of your integration wherever they are.
- You send this code from your server as a POST request to https://app.asana.com/-/oauth_token with your `client_secret` to Asana for a refresh token. This is where your application actually asks for credentials; the token given in the previous phases simply acknowledges that for a short time, the user has given your app permission to ask for these credentials, and your `client_secret` assures Asana that, for this server-side request, your app really is yours (it's like your application's password).
- We send back an `access_token` which represents (approximately) a client-user credential pair that is valid for an hour.
  You use these credentials to access our API on behalf of this user. We also send back a `refresh_token` which is long-lived, and used to get new short-lived `access_tokens` after they expire in a very similar way.

OK, so how this works with OmniAuth if I grok it correctly is that it expects to handle almost all of it. I'll be working through our omniauth example in our `ruby-asana` client library here: https://github.com/Asana/ruby-asana/blob/master/examples/omniauth_integration.rb

1. You set up OmniAuth with your client id and client secret

   ```
   use OmniAuth::Strategies::Asana, <client_id>, <client_secret>
   ```
2. A request comes in, and you don't have credentials for it.

   ```
   get '/' do
     if $client
       ...
     else
       '<a href="/sign_in">sign in to asana</a>'
     end
   end
   ```
3. The user clicks the sign in link, which (code omitted) sends them to the `sign_in` endpoint. This endpoint issues a redirect to `/auth/asana`
4. The browser requests `/auth/asana` from our server. If you look at that example, it's not implemented in our code. That's because the `/auth/:provider` is magically handled by OmniAuth.
5. This is where all the magic happens. OmniAuth handles the entire login flow above: send browser to our `oauth_authorize` above, then receive the callback and sticks the relevant params in the environment such that it knows "we just got the short lived code". By the time these lines get hit:

   ```
   creds = request.env["omniauth.auth"]["credentials"].tap { |h| h.delete('expires') }
   strategy = request.env["omniauth.strategy"]
   ```

you are inside a callback that OmniAuth has intercepted, gotten the needed creds, and set the creds in the environment. You shouldn't have to handle the oauth callback and token exchange manually.

---

Now, with the code you provided, I notice a few things right off:

1. You are causing the popup cycle to happen client side. It may be (and I strongly suspect) that this won't work with OmniAuth - it expects to handle the whole OAuth flow.
2. Based on the code snippet you provided, you aren't serving this out of a request-response cycle in the controller, rather, it appears that this is in the controller body and not out of an instance method. It may be a typo, but this needs to be in a method that is called back to outside of Rails (that is, a route must point to this a controller method that Asana can use to handle the browser request).
3. You shouldn't have to look at `request.headers`, I think - I'm not sure what the issues might be with `request.env`, but I suspect they may be unrelated to the API-only nature of your app. Are you sure that this is because it's API-only? After adding in the middleware, did you double-check that you can't access `request.env`? My hunch would be that persistent data in `request.env` will still be there, only *it* would require on the middleware being added in to do this. The instructions on OmniAuth simply say that you need to have a session store for your API - which makes sense to me, because APIs don't necessarily need to store state across requests, OmniAuth is telling you to put a session store back in.

I know this is a lot of info, but hopefully it helps you get on the right track. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you Matt! Your very detailed response gave me all the information I need to get the authentication working. Much appreciated!